# How to use more complex queries for Push notifications in Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a schema that looks something like:

```
Installation <user, etc>
User <id, contact info, etc>
activities <fromUser, toUser, type[follow, like, share]>
...
```

I want to occasionally fire off a push notification to someone's followers. I can get the follows for someone like so:

```
var followsQuery = new Parse.Query("activity");
followsQuery.equalTo("toUser", user.id);
followsQuery.equalTo("type", "follow");
```

.. and iterate through the follows and call Parse.Push.send for each of them, but I don't think this is the best way to go about doing this, and I'm worried about this timing out for people with large number of followers.

How do I form the pushQuery so as to form a join with the user and activities tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a channel for each user called "follow_[objectId]" where [objectId] is that user's objectId. Whenever a user follows someone, add that someone's follow channel to the user's push channels. Then, whenever you want to send a push notification to someone's followers, just push to their follow channel. Their followers should be subscribed to that channel and get the push.

This can be problematic if a user follows many people. When they login, the app would have to query for all the people they follow, and subscribe to all those channels, which could take a while.